# PHPExcel Style of (presumably) Excel 2007 XML

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an .xlsx file which I need to parse in order to import the contents into a DB. I have no control over the structure of the file, so I need to work with what's inside. If I open it up, I see that several rows are rendered bold, however, using PHPExcel I am unable to obtain the Bold value of these rows.

All Style objects contain the default values. What am I doing wrong?
Link to .xlsx file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvv3jchmk6iuyzr/Internettabelle.xlsx?dl=1

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

/** @var PHPExcel $pe */
$pe = $objReader->load("Internettabelle.xlsx");

$sheet = $pe->getSheet(0) ;

$rows = $sheet->getRowIterator() ;

$first = true ;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($first) {
        $first = false ;
        continue;
    }

    $cells = $row->getCellIterator() ;
    foreach($cells as $cell) {
        $style = $cell->getStyle() ;
        var_dump($style->getFont()->getBold()) ;

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to obtain the Bold value of these rows".... are you trying to identify which cells are formatted as bold?

Comment: Exactly. The `$style->getFont()->getBold()` should return a boolean, however it is always false, even if the cell is bold.

Comment: Is the style defined for the cell? or is the actual content of the cell a rich-text object?

Comment: However, looking at your spreadsheet file I don't see anything in bold at all.... I do see two different fonts being used (Aharoni and Arial) and the Aharoni font used for the "headings" is a very dark font which might seem bold, but isn't

Comment: Hm, I admit that I only opened the file in apple Numbers, but assumed it to be formatted consistently with Excel. Maybe numbers converts the different fonts into bold/not bold if it doesn't find the fonts. I'll see if I can check for different fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference: it wasn't even bold, Apple Numbers changed different fonts into the same font, bold and regular.